# mvc3 model problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have two entities page and user.
the page has a property userId

on the create of page i have this code

```
 ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "FirstName");
```

but i want to show to the user the FirstName + " " + LastName
i tried to add a FullName property to the User model

```
 public virtual string FullName()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
```

and change the code to

```
ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "FullName");
```

but then i get an error

> 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_EA60FEF07DE73591E6CDB805AD4C97662C5746A392A085CE7E70AA1B78B0DD78' does not contain a property with the name 'FullName'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your full name is a method and not a property.

Try

```
public virtual string FullName {
    get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
}
```